# Cakephp to change image when mouse over the image

Tags: html, css, image, cakephp, hover

i have this code:

> $this->Html->image('img/button/shop.png',
>   array('url'=>array('controller' => 'shops', 'action'=> 'index'),
>   'width'=>'200px', 'class'=>'contshop'));

css:

> .contshop:hover{  background-image: url('img/button/shop2.png'); }

i want the image(shop.png) change to other image(shop2.png). But the code is not working. Anyone can help me? Thanks

Comment: Instead of throwing `$this->` share the generated html, and the css

Comment: hi, the css is mention above (.contshop).
the result show the image(shop.png), but nothing happen when mouse over the image.

Comment: imho, the hover do changes the background of your `image` element but you can't see it because of the image `shop.png` itself.

Comment: thats mean shop.png hide the background? any idea to change image(hover) in cakephp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this has nothing to do with CakePHP really. You are just trying to do a CSS hover, but you're mixing up HTML images and CSS background images.

**CSS**

```
a.contshop {
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    height:80px; /* Change to the height of your image */
    background:url('../img/button/shop.png') no-repeat;
}
a.contshop:hover {
    background-image:url('../img/button/shop2.png');
}
```

**CakePHP**

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->link('', array('controller' => 'shops', 'action' => 'index'), array('class'=>'contshop'));
?>
```

You make a link and set the image as a CSS background only, which can then be changed on hover. The problem with this particular example is on the first time you hover, you will get a short flicker of nothing while the second image loads (it will be subsequently cached and won't happen again).

***Improved Solution***

Join your two images so that they are side by side, and save as one image. Then use the following CSS, which will prevent any flicker when changing images on hover:

```
a.contshop {
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    height:80px; /* Change to the height of your image */
    background:url('../img/button/shop.png') no-repeat;
}
a.contshop:hover {
    background-position:-200px 0;
}
```